# R: data imputation divided by gender

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lapply, r-mice

I have dataset

```
mydat=structure(list(sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), emotion = c(20L, 
15L, 49L, NA, 34L, 35L, 54L, 45L), IQ = c(101L, 98L, 105L, NA, 
123L, 120L, 115L, NA)), .Names = c("sex", "emotion", "IQ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

So i want to do imputation using MICE library.

```
mydat <- mice(mydat)
complete(mydat)
```

But how can  i do imputation separately by gender, for all variables at once?

the gender 1 is man, 2 is woman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `group_by()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mice)

mydat <- mydat %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  mice() %>% 
  complete()
```

Comment: clemens, any question. How can i find out   what the principle did the library use to replace outliers? Is there a log of the method used?

Comment: You can check out https://datascienceplus.com/handling-missing-data-with-mice-package-a-simple-approach/

Answer (score 2):

A more laborious solution:

```
prep = mice(mydat, maxit = 0) 
imp_meth = prep$method
imp_meth[c("sex")] = ""
pred_m = prep$predictorMatrix
pred_m[, c("IQ", "emotion")] = 0

set.seed(123)
imputed <- mice(mydat, method = imp_meth, predictorMatrix = pred_m)
complete(imputed)
```